# Getting Pandas.groupby.shift() results with groupbyvars as cols / index?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given this trivial dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':   ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                   'two':   ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'],
                   'three': [1,   2,    3,   4,   5,   6]})
```

grouping on `one` / `two` and applying `.max()` returns me a Series indexed on the groupby vars, as expected...

```
df.groupby(['one', 'two'])['three'].max()
```

output:

```
one  two
a    c      3
b    c      4
     d      6
Name: three, dtype: int64
```

...in my case I want to `shift()` my records, by group. But for some reason, when I apply `.shift()` to the groupby object, my results don't include the groupby variables:

output:

```
df.groupby(['one', 'two'])['three'].shift()
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    5.0
Name: three, dtype: float64
```

Is there a way to preserve those groupby variables in the results, as either columns or a multi-indexed Series (as in `.max()`)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difference between `max` and `diff` - `max` aggregate values (return aggregate `Series`) and `diff` not - return same size `Series`.

So is possible append output to new column:

```
df['shifted'] = df.groupby(['one', 'two'])['three'].shift()
```

Theoretically is possible use `agg`, but it return error in pandas `0.20.3`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['one', 'two'])['three'].agg(['max', lambda x: x.shift()])
print (df1)
```

> ValueError: Function does not reduce

One possible solution is `transform` if need `max` with `diff`:

```
g = df.groupby(['one', 'two'])['three']
df['max'] = g.transform('max')
df['shifted'] = g.shift()
print (df)
  one  three two  max  shifted
0   a      1   c    3      NaN
1   a      2   c    3      1.0
2   a      3   c    3      2.0
3   b      4   c    4      NaN
4   b      5   d    6      NaN
5   b      6   d    6      5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

As what Jez explained, shift return the Serise keep the same len of dataframe, if you assign it like `max()`, will getting the error

> Function does not reduce

```
df.assign(shifted=df.groupby(['one', 'two'])['three'].shift()).set_index(['one','two'])
Out[57]: 
         three  shifted
one two                
a   c        1      NaN
    c        2      1.0
    c        3      2.0
b   c        4      NaN
    d        5      NaN
    d        6      5.0
```

Using `max` as the key , and `shift` value slice the value max row

```
df.groupby(['one', 'two'])['three'].apply(lambda x : x.shift()[x==x.max()])
Out[58]: 
one  two   
a    c    2    2.0
b    c    3    NaN
     d    5    5.0
Name: three, dtype: float64
```